# javascript string exec strange behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, string, exec

have funciton in my object which is called regularly.

```
parse : function(html)
{
    var regexp = /...some pattern.../
    var match = regexp.exec(html);
    while (match != null)
    {
        ...
        match = regexp.exec(html);
    }
    ...
    var r = /...pattern.../g;
    var m = r.exec(html);
}
```

with unchanged html the `m` returns null each other call. let's say

```
parse(html);// ok
parse(html);// m is null!!!
parse(html);// ok
parse(html);// m is null!!!
// ...and so on...
```

is there any index or somrthing that has to be reset on `html` ... I'm really confused. Why `match` always returns proper result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common behavior when you deal with patterns that have the global `g` flag, and you use the `exec` or `test` methods.

In this case the `RegExp` object will keep track of the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) where a match was found, and then on subsequent matches it will start from that `lastIndex` instead of starting from 0.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, *why doesn't the `RegExp` object being re-created when you call the function again*:

This is the behavior described for *regular expression literals*, let me quote the specification:

[**§ 7.8.5 - Regular Expression Literals**](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.5)

> ...
>
> The object is created before evaluation of the containing program or function begins. Evaluation of the literal produces a reference to that object; it does not create a new object.
>
> ....

You can make a simple proof by:

```
function createRe() {
  var re = /foo/g;
  return re;
}

createRe() === createRe(); // true, it's the same object
```

You can be sure that is the same object, because *"two regular expression literals in a program evaluate to regular expression objects that never compare as `===` to each other even if the two literals' contents are identical"*, e.g.:

```
/foo/ === /foo/; // always false...
```

However this behavior is respected on all browser but not by IE, which initializes a new RegExp object every time.

Comment: Yea I was suspecting something like that, but how come those regex variables are not gc-ed and being reset? I believe each time I call parse() the new scope should be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this behavior as it might be needed in this case, simply set

```
var r = /...pattern.../g;
var m = r.exec(html);
r.lastIndex=0;
```

This worked for me.