# Javascript Regex returns null on subsequent calls when used with global flag

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript string exec strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807670/javascript-string-exec-strange-behavior)

I have a regex and i am using like this

```
new_regex = /^[+-]?(\d+).*\s+(\d+).*\s+([\d\.]+)/g

>>  /^[+-]?(\d+).*\s+(\d+).*\s+([\d\.]+)/g

myregex = new RegExp(new_regex)

>> /^[+-]?(\d+).*\s+(\d+).*\s+([\d\.]+)/g

subject = "+39° 44' 39.28\""
>>  "+39° 44' 39.28""
```

Above works for every other time i execute following:

```
myregex.exec(subject)
>> ["+39° 44' 39.28", "39", "44", "39.28"]
```

second time when i execute it gives null

```
 myregex.exec(subject)
 >> null
```

Comment: This answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Comment: @PhilParsons there is no mention in that answer that it's the `g` flag in the regex that causes this `.exec` behavior. The one apsillers posted just as I wrote this is much better

Comment: @Esailija no but the question asked is "Why RegExp with **global** flag in Javascript give wrong results?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's how `.exec` works with the global flag. If you pass it the same subject, it will advance to the next match, until it finds no matches and returns `null`:

```
var str = "1111",
    re = /1/g;


re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str) // null
```

You can reset it by changing the subject before `execing` again:

```
re.exec("") //Will reset it.
```

Example of reset:

```
var str = "1111",
    re = /1/g;

re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(""); //Reset
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str); //["1"]
re.exec(str) // null
```

Comment: very precise explanation. i got the point. thnx again