# Javascript exec maintaing state

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently trying to build a little templating engine in Javascript by replacing tags in a html5 tag by find and replace with a regex.

I am using exec on my regular expression and I am looping over the results. I am wondering why the regular expressions breaks in its current form with the /g flag on the regular expression but is fine without it?

Check the broken example and remove the /g flag on the regular expression to view the correct output.

```
var TemplateEngine = function(tpl, data) {
  var re = /(?:&lt;|<)%(.*?)(?:%&gt;|>)/g, match;
  while(match = re.exec(tpl)) {  
    tpl = tpl.replace(match[0], data[match[1]])
  }

  return tpl;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stephanv/u5d9en7n/

Can somebody explain to me a little bit more on depth why my example breaks exactly on:

```
<p><%more%></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is explained in [*javascript string exec strange behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807670/javascript-string-exec-strange-behavior).

The solution you need is actually a `String.replace` with a callback as a replacement:

```
var TemplateEngine = function(tpl, data) {
  var re = /(?:&lt;|<)%(.*?)(?:%&gt;|>)/g, match;
  return tpl.replace(re, function($0, $1) { 
     return data[$1] ? data[$1] : $0;
  });
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5d9en7n/2/)

Here, the regex finds all non-overlapping matches in the string, sequentially, and passes the match to the callback method. `$0` is the full match and `$1` is the Group 1 contents. If `data[$1]` exists, it is used to replace the whole match, else, the whole match is inserted back.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex. When using the g flag the object that you store the regex in (re) will keep track of the position of the last match in the `lastIndex` property and the next time you use that object the search will start from the position of `lastIndex`.

To solve this you could either manually reset the `lastIndex` property each time or not save the regex in an object and use it inline like so:

```
while(match = /(?:&lt;|<)%(.*?)(?:%&gt;|>)/g.exec(tpl)) {
```